# Crear un array de "n" elementos en mongoDB

Tags: javascript, nodejs, typescript, mongodb, moongose

estoy creando una query en mongoDB usando aggregation pero no sé como manejarlo, acá dejo el ejemplo de lo que quiero hacer:
Suponiendo que tengo una colección **users** con estos elementos:

```
[
    {
      "id": 1,
      "nombre": "Andres",
      "numeroPagos": 2
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "nombre": "Manuel",
      "numeroPagos": 3
    }
]
```

y quiero obtener algo como

```
[
        {
            "id": 1,
            "nombre": "Andres",
            "pagos": [
                {"idPago": 1, "nombre": "Pago 1"},
                {"idPago": 2, "nombre": "Pago 2"}
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "nombre": "Manuel",
            "pagos": [
                {"idPago": 1, "nombre": "Pago 1"},
                {"idPago": 2, "nombre": "Pago 2"},
                {"idPago": 3, "nombre": "Pago 3"}
            ]
        }
 ]
```

Donde el numero de elementos de **pagos** sea el valor de **numeroPagos** de la colección inicial.

Quiero hacerlo solo usando aggregation.

Creé esta aggregation

```
db.users.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      id:1,
      nombre:1,

    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$id",
      pagos: {
        $push : {
          idPago: 1,
          nombre: "Pago 1"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Y como resultado obtengo este array

```
[
  {
    "_id": 2,
    "pagos": [
      {
        "idPago": 1,
        "nombre": "Pago 1"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "pagos": [
      {
        "idPago": 1,
        "nombre": "Pago 1"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Pero no es el resultado que quisiera obtener, alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Es posible hacerlo, sin duda. Pero, ¿qué has intentado o investigado? Una consulta así aparece en la documentación.

Comment: No encontré algo como tal, solo hacer $push pero esto lo hacen manualmente  1 por 1, mi duda va a como hacerlo en una especie de bucle para generar esa lista

Comment: Pues agrega lo que hayas intentado. Sólo falta eso para que tu pregunta esté completa. Haz clic en [edit] y agrega lo que haga falta, incluyendo ese último comentario que pones. Saludos

Comment: Ya lo agregué, alguna sugerencia por favor?

Comment: Esa estructura de los pagos viene de otra coleccion? o si un documento dice que `numeroPagos=2` te inventas el id y el nombre de los pagos correspondientes?